# how can i run a chrome extension content script on a page right before i navigate away from that page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the user selection of a page via a content script at the moment that I navigate away from it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not totally clear to me, what do you mean with the user selection?. Can you explain a little bit more what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hey Syred, sorry I wasn't more clear. I mean the text the user has selected/highlighted with his mouse on the page.

Comment: Typically I would just execute a content script to do this, but in this case I am trying to do it on the "navigate away from page to new page" event. Which doesn't exist in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I investigated a little about what you want to do, and this is what I found:

You can detect when the user want to navigate away with this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

and you can get the selection of the user this way:

```
var getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Now if we merge this both functions to work together we could make something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return getSelected();
}
```

All this code should be in your content script, I'm not sure why you want to get the selection, but if it is for saving it on your DB or for further processing you can send the selection of the user to a background.html page I don't know if you are familiar with them but here is a link, http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html ,
to accomplish this you can use the message passing api for the chrome extensions:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

I have been working with this for 3 weeks now and it is pretty straight forward, just make sure you have a clear view of how the architecture of your extension is configured because that can save you a lot of time figuring out the data flow.

That will lead us to a code on our content script similar to this one:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({userSelection:getSelected()});
}
```

you just have to listen in your background page for the request like this:

```
var receiveMessage= function() {
                    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
                        //Do something
                   });
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Syred... onbeforeunload is what I was looking for!